# How to prevent react native FlatList from removing items when they go offscreen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using FlatList to display a list of components including texts + images (loaded from url) of about 100/200 items. I chose FlatList over ScrollView because it provides handful props (such as "onViewableItemsChanged").
However, since my list isn't so big, I'd like to keep the items loaded and mounted when they go offscreen, unlike the default behaviour of FlatList, and I can't find how to do this.

I'm surprised I didn't find discussion on the topic so I may think about this in the wrong way but I've been stuck for quite a long time now and I can't find anything that would help me refine my search.

Any help or explanation on this behaviour of FlatList (and how to de-activate it) is welcome.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the actual problem that you are facing?

Comment: My problem is: when I scroll up fast I have blank space and, if I lose connection, I lose the images that had been loaded while scrolling down. It's not ideal in terms of user experience, a bit frustrating...

Comment: Have you thought about using [FastImage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image)? This would cache your images on the device so that they wouldn't be lost.

Answer (score 0):

`FlatList` was created with the purpose of loading on-screen elements fast and unloading them as soon as they leave the view window. That improves performance of your list. I don't think there is any way to turn off this feat. If you have to do it by any means, then probably you need to implement you own FlatList, just without this feature.

Comment: I was afraid I'd be answered this... ok, thanks for the feedback! It's worth creating my own component for this project but, at least, I can stop looking for a solution in FlatList doc.